# MySQL Error 1064 in Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I'm very much a beginner at Drupal development, MySQL, and pretty much everything, so this may seem trivial, but I would really appreciate any help I can get here.
I'm getting this error, and I'm not really sure what's wrong, because everything was working fine before, and I didn't change anything around the area that it mentions since the last time it was working perfectly.

The exact error is:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC' at line 3: SELECT n.nid AS nid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {embryo_log} a ON n.nid = a.nid WHERE (n.type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (a.expiration_date > :db_condition_placeholder_1_0) ORDER BY n.sticky DESC, n.changed DESC ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => embryo_log [:db_condition_placeholder_1_0] => -1 ) in embryo_log_all() (line 599 of /data/www/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/embryo_log/embryo_log.module)."

Here is the entire function that the error is referencing, because I don't know what might be relevant:

```
function embryo_log_all($option = NULL, $action = NULL) {
  $nodes_per_page = variable_get('embryo_log_per_page', variable_get('default_nodes_main', 10));
  $output = '<div class="embryo_log">';

  // If the optional param is numeric, assume it is a node or term id.
  if (is_numeric($option)) {
    if ($action == 'group') {
      // Get all embryo_log with this term.
      // TODO Change fully to a dynamic query
      $result = db_query("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} tn USING (nid) WHERE n.type = :n.type AND n.status = :n.status AND tn.tid = :tn.tid", array(':n.type' => 'embryo_log', ':n.status' => 1, ':tn.tid' => $option));
      foreach ($result as $nid) {
        $embryo_log = node_load($nid->nid);
        $output .= '<h2>' . check_plain($embryo_log->title) . '</h2>';
        $build = node_view($embryo_log);
        $output .= drupal_render($build);
      }

      return $output . '</div>';
    }
    else {
      $embryo_log = node_load($option);
      // If it is an embryo_log, ok, else ignore it.
      if ($embryo_log != NULL) {
        if ($embryo_log->type == 'embryo_log') {
          $build = node_view($embryo_log, 'full');
          // Plain node title
          $outp = '<h2>' . check_plain($embryo_log->title) . '</h2>';
          $build['#node']->title = '';  // Don't render title
          return $outp . drupal_render($build);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (user_access('edit embryo_log')) {
    $args = array(-1);
  }
  else {
    $args = array(gmdate("U"));
  }    

//  $query = "SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {embryo_log} a ON n.nid=a.nid
//    WHERE n.type='embryo_log' AND a.expiration_date > %d
//    ORDER BY " . variable_get('embryo_log_page_order', 'n.sticky DESC, n.changed DESC');
  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit($nodes_per_page);
  $query->innerJoin('embryo_log', 'a', 'n.nid = a.nid');
  $query->condition('n.type', 'embryo_log', '=')
    ->condition('a.expiration_date', $args, '>')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->orderBy(variable_get('embryo_log_page_order', 'n.sticky, n.changed'), '');
//  $query_result = pager_query(db_rewrite_sql($query, 'n', 'nid'), $nodes_per_page, 0, NULL, $args);
  $query_result = $query->execute();

  foreach ($query_result as $nid) {
    $embryo_log = node_load($nid->nid);
    $build = node_view($embryo_log, $option);
    $output .= drupal_render($build);
  }

  $output .= '</div>';
  $output .= theme('pager', array('tags' => NULL));

  return $output;
}
```

And the line in there that is specifically being referenced in the error (line 599) is the one towards the bottom that says `$query_result = $query->execute();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, because everything looks fine to me, and I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: multi-query issue going on here? It barfs on 2nd command? Well actually it isn't a 2nd command. It is an unfinished string or residue junk of an Array

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to put two variables in one call to `orderBy`. If you want to order by multiple fields, you have to call `orderBy` separately for each field: `->orderBy('field1')->orderBy('field2')`

Comment: I assume `variable_get('embryo_log_page_order')` is returning the string `n.sticky ASC, n.changed DESC`. Drupal is putting that into the `ORDER BY` clause, and then adding its own `ASC` after it because that's the default for `orderBy`.

Comment: Use the query in quote directly and see what will happen